# Render Does Not Display Changes Until All Promises Are Resolved

Tags: reactjs, promise, electron

I am trying to create a React component with a function `append` that behaves like `console.log`.
The current situation is that I have a list of URLs to download sequentially and would like to provide the user with progress in real-time.

Here is my component:

```
async componentDidMount() {
        ...
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            this.downloadFile(files[i].url, files[i].filename);
        }
       ...
    }

append(text) {
        var newMessage = this.state.message+"\n"+text;
        this.setState({message: newMessage});
    }
```

Where `downloadFile` is an async. I am using Electron and `ipcRenderer.sendSync('download-file')` returns are promise that resolves when the file has completed saving.

```
    async downloadFile(url, filename) {
        await ipcRenderer.sendSync('download-file', {url: url, filename: filename});
        this.append("append file: " + filename);
    }
```

When the program runs, React does not display the updated display message until the final `ipcRenderer.sendSync` promise resolves. I inspected the code and found that `componentDidMount()` and `render()` both complete but the component does not actually display any changes until the entire execution completes.

How can I get React to actually render the updated `message`?
Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Note: `ipcMain.on('download-file')` uses `event.returnValue = new Promise` as a return (idk if this makes a difference)

Comment: It seems you confused [`sendSync` for `invoke`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer)

Comment: The promise returned by `sendSync` executes and resolves. Thaks for pointing out `invoke` but it seems setting `event.returnValue = new Promise` and `invoke` can accomplish the same thing. hmmm.

Comment: Oh, you say you're trying to send a promise back (synchronously)? That's weird, I wouldn't have expected that to work, given "*Arguments will be serialized with the Structured Clone Algorithm, just like `window.postMessage`, so prototype chains will not be included. Sending Functions, Promises, Symbols, WeakMaps, or WeakSets will throw an exception.*"

Comment: The promise works. The issue is with React. I expected `this.setState` to update the display is called- but for some reason, it waits until all executions are are complete before rendering.

Comment: I'm pretty certain it doesn't. Did you actually log the result of `ipcRenderer.sendSync(…)` (without the `await`)? I would guess it's not a promise, but the result of the promise. Assigning `.returnValue` doesn't send back the promise, but rather waits for the promise to fulfill and *then* sends back the result. The `sendSync()` call does block for that time. Switching to `invoke` should fix this (and seems more appropriate anyway).